# Where do I ask IoT hardware related questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question regarding some IoT related hardware. Where is the right place to ask such questions?

**Example Question:** I am using [Banner DMX 100 Wireless Gateway](https://www.bannerengineering.com/us/en/products/part.95652.html) and When i tried to read values from it using the Modbus TCP then it gives me values for sometime but after that it just hangs and stops responding. 
It then needs a power cycling to bring the unit back on-line.
Again it works for some hour and then again the same thing.

Has anyone else faced this issue ? Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: Jason C's answer is correct about the IoT site being suitable, as far as I can tell from your post. If you're not sure if your question would be on-topic there, [edit] with an example question here so we can take a look (or visit [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/chat-of-things)).

Answer (score 7):

[There is an IoT site](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) dedicated to IoT. However, please be sure to take their tour and [read their topic guidelines](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.